# Gpu name not detected tensorflow 2.2.0

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I updated tensorflow to **2.2.0** and correspondingly

```
    nvcc - 11.0
    cudnn - 11.0
    GPU - GTX 1050 ti
```

While running the following code

```
    print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I faced the following output

```
    [name: "/device:CPU:0"
    device_type: "CPU"
    memory_limit: 268435456
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 12436950237915670665
    , name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
    device_type: "XLA_CPU"
    memory_limit: 17179869184
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 11900640710651469327
    physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
    , name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
    device_type: "XLA_GPU"
    memory_limit: 17179869184
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 6061376473165052950
    physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
    ]
```

I could not see **gtx 1050ti** listed anywhere, though I can see GPU mentioned for device 0, probably meaning inbuilt GPU of **intel**.

What are the compatible versions for **1050ti** in terms of tensorflow and Cuda?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following command

```
    print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

and the result was **null**. Does this mean the GPU is not detected?

Comment: I ran the same command at another machine @Dr.Snoopy, and it came back with the clear list of GPU's, also stating its computing capacity i.e. 1080 ti , 6.1 etc.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy could you please point out which line among the o/p concretely suggests the detection of the gpu?

Comment: Yo uhave a XLA_GPU device, it would not be there if it did not detect a GPU. The list of devices is not really that helpful, the output of TensorFlow has more information about what can be a problem, for example it should say something like this: Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5560 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:20:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

Comment: can you please check the update @Dr.Snoopy?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy the following command returned empty - print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

Comment: I told you to stop looking at the list of devices and instead look at the output of TensorFlow when running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) provides info on compatible versions of Cuda, tensorflow and Cudnn to get the gpu detected. For the versions **tensorflow 2.2.0** , **Cudnn7.4** and **Cuda 10.1** , **python 3.8**, I was able to get the following output

```
    [name: "/device:CPU:0"
    device_type: "CPU"
    memory_limit: 268435456
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 4549764507052008926
    , name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
    device_type: "XLA_CPU"
    memory_limit: 17179869184
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 5130440468361087955
    physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
    , name: "/device:GPU:0"
    device_type: "GPU"
    memory_limit: 3136264601
    locality {
    bus_id: 1
    links {
    }
    }
    incarnation: 8742529146709444949
    physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 
    0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
    , name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
    device_type: "XLA_GPU"
    memory_limit: 17179869184
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 12774508348529661585
    physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
    ]
    [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```